# Superposition of two electromagnetic waves and momentum

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, superposition, poynting-vector

Electromagnetic waves follows superposition principle. So that we can simply add the fields of waves to calculate the final field. Then let's think there are two waves that are moving through x-axis and y-axis. If we control the phase difference well, we can make a situation like figure.

[image: Two electromagnetic waves]

In the figure with some $t=t_0$, you can see that there is a poynting vector has a z-axis component. In initial condition, there was no z-axis component of momentum. This doesn't seem right.

What did I miss?(or miscalculated) Why there is a strange momentum out there?

**edit: I thought that if two coherent lights have identical frequency, the direction of poynting vector will be always +z. So that the z-component doesn't vanish in average. Is there something wrong with my thoughts?**

Comment: Beautiful observation. Personally I would say the 'problem' is from Maxwells equation when we derive Poyntings theorem we only get a statement about divergence of S. Then the interpretation of S itself is slightly arbitrary. (Like take a constant E and constant B field, do you think there is momentum transfer perpendicular to them?)

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is correct. For two coherent waves there is a z-component of momentum density. Note that it vanishes on average.

Extension:
Let me explain. We are superposing to plane waves. Your picture shows the situation only in one point and at one time. There are also points where ${\bf E}$ and ${\bf E'}$  are (anti-)parallel and the z momentum component vanishes. In other points ${\bf E}' \times {\bf B}$, or ${\bf E} \times {\bf B'}$, points in the -z direction. The average of $P_z$ over a square of sides $\lambda$ in the xy plane vanishes.

More generally, you should consider the full energy-momentum distribution. The contribution of the cross terms ${\bf E} \times {\bf B'}$ and ${\bf E}' \times {\bf B}$ to this energy-momentum distribution average to zero.

Note that at every point and time the energy-momentum is conserved. Specifically, the rate of change of momentum equals the divergency of the stress.

In conclusion, all things add up. Still your observation remains interesting as it point out a paradoxical, physically inconsequential, interaction between the two waves.

Comment: Don't quite understand why it vanishes on average. Assuming the waves have the same frequency, when the phase changes by $\pi$ all the E and B arrows reverse. Doesn't that leave the direction of the Poynting vector unchanged?

Comment: I thought exactly same. Can you explain me why it vanishes on average?

Comment: @ littlegiant I don't think it does vanish on average. I'm thinking, though, that there may be a loop-hole in your argument... For e-m waves we know that /= /
in which / is the rate of propagation of energy through a surface and / is the rate of propagation of momentum through that surface. But can we apply this to an *arbitrary* superposition of fields in which there is propagation of energy, as given by the Poynting vector? The waves, as we know, pass through each other; neither is propagating in the direction of the Poynting vector. Your thoughts?

Comment: @PhilipWood I could be really wrong here, but as you pointed out, there's just superposition at one single point in space - I don't think this superposition is therefore a wave and doesn't itself transport energy or momentum. 

To derive Poynting's Theorem, you can integrate the energy density in the EM field over a finite volume V - not sure the derivation will work for a single point. Therefore, I'm not sure the Poynting vector has much meaning for interference just at a single point?

Comment: @PhilipWood Yes, as you said it is not propagating. But I think even it is not propagating, it still can have energy and momentum. Well, actually static electromagnetic field also has momentum, though its momentum is cancelled out by "hidden momentum". But in this case, there is no particles to create the "hidden momentum". So I thought that something is weird, and posted my question.

Comment: @Shrey I think you pointed out right. Poynting vector is a kind of density, so we need to integrate in volume to obtain the momentum. But doing simillar to Riemann sum in calculus, I think we can still make the z-component be non-zero value.(like setting integral range really small)